# Regex for number + % + gw

Tags: python, regex

I'm having issues to get my code to work correctly and was hoping for a little help.

These are allowed:
25
25%
25%gw
25gw

The code that I have is allowing the letters gw to be acceptable inverted but I do not want that to be allowed.

Not allowed:
25%wg
25wg

What did I do wrong?

```
[0-9]{1,9}([\.][0-9]{1,2})?[\%]?[\w{g}][\w{w}]?$
```

Comment: Try [`^[0-9]{1,9}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?%?(?:gw)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/F8abfM/1)

Comment: @Jesse Did that work? BTW, what is the method you are using? Please show the code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew & marvel308 - Both options worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work for you

```
[0-9]{1,9}([\.][0-9]{1,2})?[\%]?(?:gw)?$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/TPMCeE/2)